# How can I loop through string and replace all periods except the last one?

Tags: javascript, loops, replace, each

Let's say I have a string like this:

`var test = my.long.file.name.zip`

I am getting the total number of periods in this string with javascript like so:

```
var dots = (test.match(/\./g) || []).length;
```

I would then like to replace all of the periods in the string with underscores if there is more than one period in the string.

```
   if(dots>"1"){   
     var newname = test.replace(/\./g, "_");
     console.log(newname);
    }
```

The problem is that this is replacing all of the periods.  I would like to keep the last on intact.  So what I would like the `newname` variable to  read as would be:

`my_long_file_name.zip`

My guess is that I should use `$.each()` somehow to iterate over all except the last one to change the name.  How should I do this?

Comment: There is nothing jQuery about this - its vanilla javascript so I updated your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I am just doing this in a jQuery function so I was focused on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont necessarily need a loop, you could do it with a more complex regex, which uses a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html)

The regex `/\.(?=.*\.)/g` finds periods, but only where there is a subsequent period somewhere further along, which means the last one is not matched.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var input = "my.long.file.name.zip"
  var result = input.replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g,'_')

  alert(result);
}
```

Comment: This wins it for the most concise code with an easy to follow explanation.  Thanks.

Comment: Additionally `"my.long.....file.name.zip".replace(/\.{1,}(?=.*\.)/g,'_')` to replace dot sequences by just one underscore: `"my_long_file_name.zip"`

Answer (score 2):

Consider splitting the string on `'.'`, then re-joining all but the last with `'_'`:

```js
var test = "my.long.file.name.zip";

parts = test.split('.');

var plen = parts.length;

if (plen > 1) {
  test = parts.slice(0, plen - 1).join('_') +
    "." +
    parts[plen - 1];
}

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

a lookahead group in regex will work:

```js
var test = 'my.long.file.name.zip';
var result = test.replace(/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/g, '_');
alert(result);
```

this matches a dot followed by ('anything but dot' and another dot), replacing only what is outside the group

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = 'my.long.file.name.zip';
var last_index = test.lastIndexOf('.');
var newname = test;

if (-1 !== last_index) {
  newname = test.replace(/\./g, '_');
  newname = newname.substring(0, last_index).concat('.', newname.substring(last_index + 1));
}

console.log(newname);
```